# How to create a multi step registration form in react-native?

Tags: react-native-ios

I'm trying to create a multi-step form in react native which consists of personal information on first step, address details on second step and review the info and submit button on third step.
All fields should pass through validation.

Comment: You can use SegmentedControl component and add each step as a separate component for each step of the registration.

Comment: As I am new to react native, is there any online source to see an example to build the multi step form. help would be appreciated.

Comment: Here you go, https://github.com/srdjan/react-multistep; https://css-tricks.com/the-magic-of-react-based-multi-step-forms/